# Rails: documenting post endpoint which consumes json params using swagger-blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, swagger, swagger-2.0

Using swagger-blocks in rails, would i document a post endpoint which consumes a single json body such as:

`{
"id":"1",
"name": "bill",
"age":"22"
}`

No matter what I do, my tests keep saying that my setup is not valid Swagger 2.0 JSON schema.

Below is the code I am using to generate my documentation:

```
swagger_path '/list/add' do
        operation :post do
          key :summary, 'Add person to list'
          parameter name: :id, in: :body, required: true, type: :string
          parameter name: :name, in: :body, required: true, type: :string
          parameter name: :age, in: :body, required: true, type: :string

          response 200 do
            key :description, 'Successfully added to list'
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score -1):

The JSON seems correct syntactically except that "id" should be generated automatically by default if you are trying to create. You may check this [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) for violations.

Comment: I should have been more specific earlier, but the code which i am using to generate my swagger documentation seems to generate errors(not the input params). I've just added this to the original post as well.